# Close off an endpoint on node.js server by via Kubernetes

Tags: python, node.js, docker, kubernetes

I have a Docker image which runs a python subprocess, which is a `node.js` server exposing an end point `/check`. The whole thing is put inside a Kubernetes pod and uses `/check` as the readinessProbe endpoint.

Now at some point, I want to close this endpoint or force-fail all the requests coming at it. Ideally, I want to do this via higher-level entities (i.e. Kubernetes lifecycle hooks) so as not to touch the lower-level implementation (such as opening a new endpoint /stop that switch some boolean flag and force the /check to fail)

Is that possible at all? If not, what is the best alternative?

Comment: _runs a python subprocess, which is a node.js server_ that's very weird

Comment: _to do this via higher-level entities (i.e. Kubernetes lifecycle hooks)_ what does that mean?

Comment: _runs a python subprocess, which is a node.js server_ yeah it is but it's a legacy design I'm trying not to change immediately. It runs two subprocesses actually so I guess the python script is just a convenient start up script

Comment: _to do this via higher-level entities_ means I don't want to get down to the actual implementation of the server if possible. I try to see if the tools (i.e. Kubernetes) already provides solution for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that possible at all? If not, what is the best alternative?

I believe there are a few:

- remote address filtering
- magic headers
- a formal proxy container

#### remote address

Requests to `/check` coming from kubernetes will come from the Node's SDN IP address (so if a Node's SDN subnet is `10.10.5.0/24`, then requests will come from 10.10.5.1), so you could permit the checks from the `.1` of the `/24` assigned to the Pod

#### magic headers

The `httpGet` `readinessProbe` allows `httpHeaders:` so you could turn on HTTP Basic auth for `/check` and then put the `- name: Authentication value: Basic xxyyzz==` in the `httpHeaders:`

#### a formal proxy container

Add a 2nd container to the `Pod` that runs `haproxy` and filters `/check` requests to return 401 or 404 or whatever you want. Since all containers in a Pod share the same networking namespace, configuring `haproxy` to speak to your node.js server will be super trivial, and your `readinessProbe` (as well as `liveliness`) can continue to use the URL because only kubernetes will have access to it by using the non-haproxy container's `port`. To complete that loop, point the `Service` at the `haproxy` container's port.

Comment: The proxy container seems to be the most flexible solution but also one I'm trying not to use. These suggestions are solid though I will try to see if I can implement any of them